# Normalize is called only once in redux form

Tags: redux, normalization, redux-form

i'm using a normalizer for pad from left a user's input.
My function is this:

```
export const padLeft = (num, len) => (
  len > num.toString().length ? '0'.repeat(len - num.toString().length) + num
    : num
);
```

and my normalizer is this:

```
const normalizeCid = (value) => {
  return padLeft(value, 8);
};
```

When i use it in my Field component like this:

```
<Field
        id="searchCif"
        name="searchCif"
        floatingLabelText={SEARCHVIEW_HINT_CIF}
        component={InputTextField}
        disabled={(props.afm !== undefined)}
        normalize={normalizeCid}
      />
```

and i type an input for example 2 it shows me 00000002 which is correct but when i type 23 the zeros are not reducing. It shows me 000000023. Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you checked with console.log that the function is in fact only running once, or does it run with each updated value but produce unexpected results?

Comment: Yes it's running only once. But why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the function `normalizeCid` *is* running with each value change, but first time you run it and type '2', the value that get passed to `padLeft` is 2, and it returns **and displays** 00000002.

Then, when you add a '3' to to the displayed value (00000002), the value that gets passed into `padLeft` is 000000023, which has length of 9, which is greater than 8, so it just returns the original value.

So the issue is faulty logic in the `padLeft` function.

The `padLeft` function seems to work as long as it gets passed a number without any leading zeros, so we could possibly fix the issue by using Regex to remove the leading zeros before we pass the value to `padLeft`:

```js
const normalizeCid = (value) => {
  const noLeadingZeros = value.toString().replace(/\b(0+)/, '');
  return padLeft(noLeadingZeros, 8);
};
const padLeft = (num, len) => (
  // num is already a string now
  len > num.length ? '0'.repeat(len - num.toString().length) + num
    : num
);
```

**NOTE**: This suggestion probably doesn't work with all edge cases, so you may have to add some extra condition somewhere.

Comment: I see.. thanks a lot. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: No problem! :) I think the suggested solution maybe doesn't work with all edge cases (like really large numbers), so you may have to add some extra condition somewhere. But you know better than I how those edge-cases should be handled. So I think you can modify the function yourself to fit your needs.

Comment: I changed the Regex slightly, because before it would remove the first zeroes it encountered, even if the zeroes where not first.  "200"  (would give you 2). But the new one should work better with `value.toString().replace(/\b(0+)/, '')`

Comment: One question, with this approach i can't erase the input. I'M pressing backspace and the number are not erasing

Comment: You mean you cant erase the zeroes? Try adding `if(noLeadingZeros.length == 0) return value;`  before the return line, in `normalizeCid`.  I'm not sure exacly how you want the input to behave. You can see how it behaves on the input fields here: https://jsfiddle.net/jonahe/4non6918/8/